# Web Flow Ignores STATE_SAVING_METHOD_CLIENT for JSF Views?

Tags: java, jsf, spring-webflow

I have a web app that is using Spring Web Flows with Facelets as the view technology. I have set the context param

```
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But I was noticing that my Session Sizes were getting quite large. Upon further investigation I realized that the FlowViewStateManager was holding extremely large references to objects. When I look at the code for this class I see the following method

`public boolean isSavingStateInClient(FacesContext context) {`

```
if (!JsfUtils.isFlowRequest()) {
    return delegate.isSavingStateInClient(context);
} 
else {
    return false;
}
}
```

So it appears like Web Flow will save the JSF view state on thee server side regardless of the context param if the request is a flow request. What is the reasoning behind this, and is there anyway I can store the state client side with Web Flow?